# Javascript switch with string variable not working

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

Could anyone tell me why the below switch is not working?

```
var String=new String('String #1');

document.write(String);

document.write(' Check ');

switch(String)
{

    case 'String #1' : 
    document.write('String Number 1');
    break;
    default: document.write('wrong string');
}
```

The output is:  String #1 Check wrong string

Comment: Why did you name the string a builtin function name?

Comment: ^ that, you should be getting `String is not a constructor` error

Comment: a) Don't create `String` instances b) don't overwrite `String` c) don't `switch` on `String` objects

Comment: When I name it differently, e.g. MyString, the same still happens.

Comment: No errors when running this, just the output from the default statement.

Comment: If you wrote `var String = 'String #1';` it should work with no problems.

Comment: `new String('String #1') !== 'String #1'`. First is an object, second a primitive value. And yes, switch uses strict comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must compare an Object with an Object not a String with an Object. Here I compare an object with an Object :

```
var string = "String #1";
console.log(string);
console.log("Check");

switch(string)
{
    case "String #1":
    console.log("String Number 1");
    break;
    default: console.log("wrong string");
}
```

Comment: Correction "here you are comparing a string to a string" :)

Answer (score 4):

String is a constructor that's builtin to JavaScript. Naming variables that shadow these constructors will cause an error:

```
TypeError: String is not a constructor
```

Rename the `String` variable and do not use the `switch` statement here because you have a String instance. `switch` statements use strict comparison (`===`) per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and the [ECMAScript 2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-caseblockevaluation). Since a string instance and literal are never 'strictly equal', comparison fails. Don't instantiate, instead use a literal:

```js
var string = "String #1";

switch(string) {
  case "String #1":
    document.write("String Number 1");
    break;
  default: 
    document.write("wrong string");
}
```

Also, I don't recommend using `document.write`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/5647260). Logging or inserting into the DOM with `createElement` and `appendChild` should work sufficiently here.

Comment: Thank you all for advising, This works:
 
 
If you wrote var String = 'String #1'; it should work with no problems. – torazaburo 56 mins ago     I will check the other options as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the object to a string using `toString()` See example https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/59x9xn3g/1/

```
<script>
var someObject =new String('String #1');
var someString = someObject.toString();
document.write(someString);

document.write(' Check ');

switch(someString)
{

    case 'String #1' : document.write('String Number 1');
    break;
    default: document.write('wrong string');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is to concat a primitive string and your string object. The result is a primitive string, which can be used in a switch statement.

```
var String=new String('String #1');

document.write(String);

document.write(' Check ');

switch('' + String)
{

    case 'String #1' : 
    document.write('String Number 1');
    break;
    default: document.write('wrong string');
}
```